# Spring @AliasFor with property for nested annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

Is it possible to have `@AliasFor` annotation pass the argument to nested annotation? Something like passing value of `name()` to nested `@Queue` annotation inside `@RabbitListener`? I basically wanted to specify multiple queues with same binding parameters to same exchange, and only vary queue name.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that for nested annotations. You probably need to think about having a custom `@Queue` annotation extension and then used it inside your `@SomeListener`. But the problem is that `@Queue` annotation cannot be extended. It has that `@Target({})`, so it is not possible at the moment.

If you really wish to have such a customization, consider to fix Spring AMQP on the matter via `@Target(ANNOTATION_TYPE)` and add some tests to demonstrate the feature and contribute it back to the framework.

Unfortunately I don't see the other way to support your request, unless you would go the to declare `Queue` beans and use just their names in that your custom annotation:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@RabbitListener
public @interface MyListener {
    
    @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class, attribute = "queues")
    String[] queues() default {};
    
}
```

Comment: One thought I had is we could expose a hook in the bean post processor to allow the user to manipulate the `MergedAnnotations` before we synthesize the new annotation - e.g. copy the value of a top level attribute into the nested attribute - something like `return MergedAnnotations.of(SomeListener.class, updateAttributes(merged.asMap()))`. I will experiment.

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to see if there is a way to do it that way. I guess I can always just define all the beans separately and wire them...

Comment: Prototype here: https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-amqp/commit/888079dda63480e9c9177745c482f645c63c737b let me know if providing a hook to allow you to modify the annotation would satisfy your requirements.